# PDO - Dynamic Query Building

Tags: php, mysql, input, pdo

is it somehow possible to built a dynamic query for PDO?

**Description:**
I Have the following function:
    function

```
saveContent($roundId,$answer,$question_de,$question_en,$files_1_1,$files_1_2,$files_2_1,$files_2_2,$files_3_1,$files_3_2) {

        $sql_pictures = "
            UPDATE ".DBPREFIX."pictures
            SET
                file_1_static=:files_1_1,
                file_1_animation=:files_1_2,
                file_2_static=:files_2_1,
                file_2_animation=:files_2_2,
                file_3_static=:files_3_1,
                file_3_animation=:files_3_2
            WHERE
                roundId=:roundId";
        try {
            $db = self::getConnection();
            $stmt_pictures = $db->prepare($sql_pictures);

            $stmt_pictures->bindParam("roundId", $roundId);
            $stmt_pictures->bindParam("files_1_1", $$question_de);
            $stmt_pictures->bindParam("files_1_2", $question_en);
            $stmt_pictures->bindParam("files_2_1", $roundId);
            $stmt_pictures->bindParam("files_2_2", $$question_de);
            $stmt_pictures->bindParam("files_3_1", $question_en);
            $stmt_pictures->bindParam("files_3_2", $question_en);

            $stmt_pictures->execute();
            $db = null;
            return true;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

The important part is in "sql_pictures". I'm calling this function by passing the necessary data into the function, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {        
            $saveContent = $helper->saveContent(
                $_POST['roundId'],
                $_POST['answer'],
                $_POST['question_de'],
                $_POST['question_en'],
                $_FILES["files_1_1"],
                $_FILES["files_1_2"],
                $_FILES["files_2_1"],
                $_FILES["files_2_2"],
                $_FILES["files_3_1"],
                $_FILES["files_3_2"]
            );  
        }
```

As some of you maybe notice, it's for a multiple file upload.
Now the main problem is, I don't want to update fields when either the string is empty (not set) or the value didn't changed (i.e $files_1_1 didn't changed or is empty).

How can I achieve that?

**Other question:**
Is it maybe better to use

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="file" name="files_1_2" id="file" />
```

for each input field?
And how can I refactor the function then?  I'm sitting on it for many hours, but no clue. A hint would be nice! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the insert/UPDATE queries dynamic query building is quite simple task. Just create an array with key names equal to field names and corresponding values and then process them in a loop.

> I don't want to update fields when either the string is empty (not set)  or the value didn't changed

the last one doesn't matter. if value didn't change - it won't be changed in the table either.
For the other values create an array with values that suits you (i.e not empty) and then use a helper function to create a SET statement dynamically. You can use one from the [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for example

> Other question:

Personally I prefer `files_1, files_2, files_3...` way as it lets me iterate over `$_FILES` array using simple foreach